# Trying To Create a Button that Changes the Background colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a button that changes the background colour of my HTMl page. 
below is the code i have however the code i have doesnt seem to work can anyone help me out?

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor() {
    var col = 
document.getElementById("body");
    if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }
    col.style.backgroundColor = 
colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex++;
}
```

```css
/* This is to Style My Button */
.button {
  position: center;
  background-color: #c2c3c4;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* 
  Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px !important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button class="button" onclick="changeColor();">Change Colour</button>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my final attempt at the code, it doesnt work however it does give me the style of button i wish, any addition or solving will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how does it not working and whether there is any error messages?

Comment: @Andreas no error messages and the button appears on my page and is clickable, however when it is clicked the background colour does not change, my css sheet does not have a set background colour.

Comment: `document.getElementById('body')` is not an ID tag, it is a body tag, you can use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` to change the background color of the body

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call your body using,

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
      var colorIndex = 0;
      function changeColor() {
          var col = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
          if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
              colorIndex = 0;
          }
          col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
          colorIndex++;
      }
```

```css
/* This is to Style My Button */
.button {
position: center;
background-color: #c2c3c4;
border: none;
font-size: 28px;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 20px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /*
Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;
text-decoration: none;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
content: "";
background: #f1f1f1;
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 300%;
padding-left: 350%;
margin-left: -20px !important;
margin-top: -120%;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
opacity: 1;
transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="changeColor();">Change Colour</button>
```

Comment: this works slightly however  it changes the background colour of the button not the web page background

Comment: @IDontKnowWhatImDoing to target the background, change `var col = document.getElementById("body");` to `var col = document.querySelector("body");` ids are different from tags

Comment: okay i got it working for all of around 30 seconds then after i refreshed the page after i had changed the colours it stopped working again so i reverted back to what you had done and it still doesnt work

Comment: @Katie.Sun i have done this and it still does not work

Comment: Use this instead var col = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want the color to be completely random instead of just picking from your index you could do this:

```js
function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

let button = document.querySelector('button')
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let r = randomInt(1, 255),
    g = randomInt(1, 255),
    b = randomInt(1, 255)
  document.body.style.background = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
})
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button>Change Color!</button>
```

Using the randomInt function, which returns a random integer between your min and max including your min and max, we can get a random value between 1 and 255. We call that function three times after our button click and store each one in a variable representing red green and blue. Then using template literals we put those values into our body background. This will assign a different rgb value to the body anytime the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the problems is because the body is not and ID, is a HTML tag, you can access it  directly with "document.body" or use "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]" (this return an array of element, in this case we need to access to the first element).

I share with you the functional code.

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor() {
    var col = document.body;
    //var col = document.getElementsByTagName ('body')[0];

    if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }
    col.style.backgroundColor = 
colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex++;
}
```

```css
/* This is to Style My Button */
.button {
  position: center;
  background-color: #c2c3c4;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* 
  Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px !important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button class="button" onclick="changeColor();">Change Colour</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tr this one.

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var i=0;
function changeColor(){
  if(i<colors.length-1){
    i=i+1; 
  }
  else{
    i=0;
  }
  $('body').css('background-color', colors[i]);  
}
```

```css
.button {
  position: center;
  background-color: #c2c3c4;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* 
  Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px !important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" onclick="changeColor();">Change Colour</button>
```